# Find all points where $\Re f(x)=0$ inside a given rectangle on the complex plane

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible to find the real roots of a complex function inside a given rectangle? I'm trying to find the real zeros of the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function). How would I go about finding all zeros in the `Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.23, 37}]` for example?

```
pzz = ToExpression[
   Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinq321/primezetazero/main/pzz", "Text"]];
Show[
Take[pzz, 100] // ListPlot, 
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {.23, 37}]}]
]
```

[image]

The real zeros of the `PrimeZetaP` function for the above were taken from [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html),
and extracted with `pzz = Catenate@Cases[image, Point[data_] :> data, Infinity];` I've since uploaded them [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinq321/primezetazero/main/pzz).

Comment: Where were the roots taken from???

Comment: @azerbajdzan from [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html) as stated in the question!

Comment: I see the link but it is not clear to me, where from that link and how you extracted them. Furthermore the roots does not seem to be roots of `PrimeZetaP[s] == 0`  as is assumed by the author of the link but rather of `Re[PrimeZetaP[s]] == 0` in which case they can not be called roots of prime zeta function.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I extracted them by downloading the notebook, and usiung `pzz = Catenate@Cases[image, Point[data_] :> data, Infinity];` from the image on the right of [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-svg/PrimeZetaRoots_1000.svg)

Comment: I see, but they are not the roots of prime zeta function as I wrote in previous comment. The author seems to have made a mistake. You can check that by plugging them into `PrimeZetaP` whether you get near zero result.

Comment: I do not consider results of first zero and 10-th zero to be close to zero: `PrimeZetaP[0.0178195 + I 0.000173417] == 1.8447*10^(-7) + 0.2346 I`, `PrimeZetaP[0.0351516 + I 7.46137] == -0.000054 + 14.48038 I`. I can say real parts are close to zero but not imaginary parts.

Comment: @azerbajdzan yes, I concede on that!

Comment: @azerbajdzan I'll update question

Comment: There was nothing wrong with the original question to find the roots. I just wanted to point out that the author of the link mistakenly presented roots of the real part as roots in general.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thanks for pointing that out though!

Answer (score 1):

If your guess is relatively close to the actual zero then this works:

```
FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s], {s, 0.1 + I 0.3}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
PrimeZetaP[s] /. %
FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s], {s, 0.6 + I 9}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
PrimeZetaP[s] /. %
FindRoot[PrimeZetaP[s], {s, 1.1 + I 24}, WorkingPrecision -> 10]
PrimeZetaP[s] /. %
```

---

```
{s -> 0.1188814636 + 0.4260430864 I}

0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I

{s -> 0.6179556663 + 8.827520647 I}

0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I

{s -> 1.061924186 + 23.71733036 I}

0.*10^-8 + 0.*10^-8 I
```

But `PrimeZetaP` seems to be computationally expensive. Just try `WorkingPrecision -> 100` instead...

So I guess it would be difficult to do the exact search in a larger area of  the complex plane.

Comment: thanks - yes, `PrimeZetaP` seems tricky to work with ..